# Excel VBA - Count Number of ActiveX ComboBoxes

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a classification of ActiveX controls that I can use to determine the number of them on a sheet?  Looking for a Shape with .Type=12 I think will determine ActiveX but is there some sort of 'subtype' I can use to determine the type of ActiveX control such as ComboBox or Label etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to count number of ActiveX control on a worksheet. Try the below code:

```
Sub try()

Dim Ws As Worksheet
Set Ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Count = 0

For Each OleObj In Ws.OLEObjects
    If OleObj.OLEType = xlOLEControl Then
        If TypeName(OleObj.Object) = "ComboBox" Then
            Count = Count + 1
        End If
    End If
Next OleObj

MsgBox "Number of ComboBoxes :" & Count

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks.  I had a lot of trouble getting the TypeName and TypeOf to work.  This is great.